# access event after some duration of UIImageView animation

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

i want method to be called after some duration of `UIImageView` animation.

like i've NSArray with 400 `UIImage` for animation with `animationDuration` 20 second. i want event to be fired after 10 second ... so how can i do that stuff ?

any help appreciable ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

pls try to be more specific, but I guess this should to the trick

Answer (score 0):

Or break them up into two
part 1
method()
part 2